# How can I set up adapter for spinner in widget from a service?

Tags: android, widget, spinner, remoteview

How is this possible through RemoteView? Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RemoteViews has a method setRemoteAdapter ([javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setRemoteAdapter%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29)) which seems like what you are looking for. It is available only from API level 11 upwards though.

Comment: True. The sad thing, that in our project we have to develop compatible with Android 1.6 (API level 4)...